# Bypass Cookie Banner with DiffBot

Tags: web-scraping, diffbot

I am trying to scrape a website, but Difbot shows me this text:

```
This website uses own and third-party cookies to improve and customize our services, produce statistical information, analyze your browsing habits, and show you advertising. For more information, please check our Cookies Policy. You can accept all cookies by clicking on ACCEPT ALL, or go to SETTINGS to manage and/or decline them. View our partners
```

I have used Webhook to see the Headers:

[image: Webhook.site]

I have tried to change the cookies parameter, but it hasn't worked.

I also want this to be available for every website not just one.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I find it quite difficult to extract website data with Diffbot.

Answer (score 0):

[You need to use X-Forward as a prefix with any header you want forwarded](https://docs.diffbot.com/reference/extract-custom-headers#direct)

```
curl --location --request GET 'api.diffbot.com/v3/article?token=MY_TOKEN&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen17uofqrlcgv.x.pipedream.net%2F' \
--header 'X-Forward-User-Agent: foobar' \
--header 'X-Forward-Referrer: Diffbot.com' \
--header 'X-Forward-Accept-Language: hr' \
--header 'X-Cookie: cookie
```

[Here is the tutorial/docs on using cookie with diff](https://docs.diffbot.com/reference/how-do-i-extract-content-behind-logins)